# ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format while using Bind variable

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to append a bind variable (:Year) and I am getting the error as "ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format".

The sql is

```
Select SUM(CASE WHEN (date_start<= to_date('01/01/'||:Year,'MM/DD/YYYY') and
                     (actual_termination_date is null or  actual_termination_date > to_date('01/01/'||:Year,'MM/DD/YYYY')))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS CJAN 
from PER_PERIODS_OF_SERVICE ppp
```

I have tried using to_char(:Year) but of no use.
Can you please let me know what is causing the issue ???

Comment: What value does `:Year` have?  That could be the problem.

Comment: :Year can have 2015 or 2016 as values
I have other case statement

CASE WHEN to_char(ppp.date_start,'yyyy') = :Year  AND to_char(ppp.date_start,'MM')='01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

This works fine

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, the logic seems simpler to express like this:

```
Select SUM(CASE WHEN extract(year from date_start) <= :Year and
                     (extract(year from actual_termination_date) >= :Year or
                      actual_termination_date is null
                     )
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS CJAN 
from PER_PERIODS_OF_SERVICE ppp
```

Perhaps that will also fix your problem.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks, But I have many Case Statements like this where I am checking for start of every month. So I need to somehow append the year. Because year can have 2015 and 2016 as values

Comment: If you have a different question, then you should ask that question.  This question seems to be about an entire year.

Comment: I just need to know how to suffix year dynamically in the 12 case statements I have (One for each month). Or is there a workaround for the approach I am following

Answer (score 0):

Used this to get the first day of the year.

trunc(to_date(:YEAR,'YYYY'),'YYYY')